# SQL EXPRESS Universal Collation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

is there a universal collation for SQL EXPRESS 2012 server?
I need to be able to save russian, czech, ... texts and read them in my program.

Changing char to nchar didnt help. I was able to save russian text, but with collation set to Czech_CI_AS, the program showed "?????" instead of the russian text. When changed to collation Kazakh_90_CI_AS, russian text was shown ok, but i couldnt save czech text (čřž) to the database (it was saved as crz).

Anyone has an idea what to do? :]

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely there is something wrong with application - it does not saves text as unicode. Collation should affect the order in case of sorting and how strings will be compared to each other, but not the content.
Here is the demo when both values czech and russian text can be retrieved:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/edcd6/1

Also may be this answer will be useful for you:
[SQL Server multi language data support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017198/sql-server-multi-language-data-support)

Comment: whow, thanks ... that might help a lot ... 
I noticed, that changing collation helps with that too, but only for one language.
This could solve my problem :]