# Translating in SQL Server 2008, using Bing Translate API.

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms, sqlclr, bing-api

Using the code examples given by Microsoft:

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Language-Translation-e3898f0a

I have enabled translation in my SQL Server 2008 database. When the input string is relatively simple, without accented characters, translation works fine.

Example call (through Management Studio):

```
SELECT [dbo].[udfCallTranslator] ('Hej','sv','en')
```

Returns:

```
Hi
```

---

The problem lies when there are special accented characters in the input:

```
SELECT [dbo].[udfCallTranslator] ('Biogasanläggningar','sv','en')
```

Returns:

```
Biogasanlaggningar
```

It should return:

```
Biogas plants
```

---

If I give the input to Microsoft's web site (https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/microsofttranslator) it translates it correctly.

If i call the underlying dll function through a let's say Windows Form application, it also translates it correctly.

So, my guess is that something isn't passed correctly from Management Studio to the underlying function.

I tried changing the editor's font to Arial Unicode MS, but nothing changed.

Any other insight on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help.

[SQL Server multi language data support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017198/sql-server-multi-language-data-support)

Have you made sure its in NVARCHAR as well as preceded all passed unicode strings with N?

```
SELECT [dbo].[udfCallTranslator] (N'Biogasanläggningar','sv','en')
```